# Como "setar" uma Query na anotação @Entity com Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Tenho a seguinte Classe:

**Aluno.java**

```
@Entity
public class Aluno implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(length=11, nullable=false)
    private int cpf;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private int rg;

    @Column(length=11,nullable=false)
    private int matricula;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataNascimento;

    /* RELACIONAMENTOS */

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="aluno")
    private List<Inscricao> inscricoes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="aluno")
    private List<Relatorio> relatorios;

    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */
    ...
}
```

Acontece que os atributos estão em várias tabelas do banco, então eu criei a Query, e passei para os DBAs da Instituição criarem as Views, o que facilitaria bastante, só que eles não estão trabalhando esses dias e preciso terminar isso até segunda, então uma alternativa era colocar as querys no código, lembro que uma vez vi um código onde a query ia próximo a anotação @Entity, alguém poderia ajudar? Como configuro isso no código?

Segue a minha Query:

```
SELECT p.nome_pessoa, a.dt_nascimento, alc.matricula, dj.numero_documento as rg, df.numero_documento as cpf 
    FROM pessoas AS p
        INNER JOIN alunos AS a ON p.id_pessoa = a.id_pessoa
        INNER JOIN acad_alunos_cursos AS alc ON alc.id_aluno = a.id_aluno
        LEFT JOIN doc_pessoas AS df ON p.id_pessoa = df.id_pessoa AND df.id_tdoc_pessoa = 1
        LEFT JOIN doc_pessoas AS dj ON p.id_pessoa = dj.id_pessoa AND dj.id_tdoc_pessoa = 3
```

Comment: Acredito que o que você busca são **NamedQueries**, você configura a anotação para a entidade.

Comment: Estou tentando a resposta do touchmx, mas como fazer se as tabelas que tenho na query (inner join, etc.) não possuem entidades?

Comment: As named queries são JPQL. Suspeito que para o seu caso é melhor criar uma classe que armazene essas Queries nativas em atributos estáticos e use o `EntityManager.createNativeQuery`. A desvantagem é que se houverem erros, serão detectados em tempo de execução, ao contrário das NamedQueries que são verificadas em tempo de deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A anotação que você precisa é uma @NamedQueries. Adicione-a acima da declaração da classe da seguinte forma:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Aluno.NOME_DA_QUERY", query = "SELECT p.nome_pessoa, a.dt_nascimento, alc.matricula, dj.numero_documento as rg, df.numero_documento as cpf 
FROM pessoas AS p
    INNER JOIN alunos AS a ON p.id_pessoa = a.id_pessoa
    INNER JOIN acad_alunos_cursos AS alc ON alc.id_aluno = a.id_aluno
    LEFT JOIN doc_pessoas AS df ON p.id_pessoa = df.id_pessoa AND df.id_tdoc_pessoa = 1
    LEFT JOIN doc_pessoas AS dj ON p.id_pessoa = dj.id_pessoa AND dj.id_tdoc_pessoa = 3")})
```

Comment: A named query entao sera em sql mesmo? Nao precisa ser em hql? Vou tentar aqui.

Comment: Deu o seguinte erro: pessoas is not mapped [SELECT p.nome_pessoa AS nome, a.dt_nascimento AS dataNascimento...]

Comment: Utilize para pessoa, alunos e afins (que representam tabelas) o nome dos objetos que os referenciam, No caso se pessoas for um objeto coloque o nome da classe pessoa (que deve ser Pessoas, em maiúsculo)

Comment: Eu não tenho uma classe Pessoa, só tenho a classe aluno. Ai aluno é formado por atributos das classes: Alunos , Pessoas, acad_alunos_cursos e doc_pessoas